# When should I use the read/writeQuery and when the read/writeFragment while working with the Apollo Cache?

Tags: javascript, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm working with the Apollo local cache and I found that the **read/writeQuery** works in the same way as **read/writeFragment**. Both of them do the same thing and the only difference at my opinion is just that the *readQuery* returns an object that contains the query name as a key and the query result as a value. The *readFragment* returns the query result object itself.

Based on the official documentation about [readQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#readquery) I could assume that it executes the query and returns the data.
About the [readFragment](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#readfragment) things look the same. The only difference is that in the case of Fragment I should pass the composed ID of the required item that Apollo cache uses itself.
But the result is totally the same as in the case of *readQuery* except that it returns the object of values.

Here is the code example.
Sorry, there are will be a lot of cumbersome boilerplate. Simple but a lot to demonstrate the problem in very detail.

The schema of the Track (I'll omit other types to reduce the code boilerplate):

```
  type Track {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    author: Author!
    thumbnail: String
    length: Int
    modulesCount: Int
    description: String
    numberOfViews: Int
    modules: [Module!]!
  }
```

The **readQuery** example with the all the Track fields:

```
const { track } = client.readQuery({
    query: gql`
      query getTrack($trackId: ID!) {
        track(id: $trackId) {
          id
          title
          author {
            id
            name
            photo
          }
          thumbnail
          length
          modulesCount
          numberOfViews
          modules {
            id
            title
            length
          }
          description
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      trackId: 'c_1',
    },
  });
```

The result is:

```
{
    "__typename": "Track",
    "id": "c_1",
    "title": "FAMOUS CATSTRONAUTS",
    "author": {
        "__typename": "Author",
        "id": "cat-2",
        "name": "Grumpy Cat",
        "photo": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593627010886-d34828365da7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjExNzA0OH0"
    },
    "thumbnail": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dety84pbu/image/upload/v1598474100/famous_cats_epuqcr.jpg",
    "length": 1916,
    "modulesCount": 5,
    "numberOfViews": 26,
    "modules": [
        {
            "__typename": "Module",
            "id": "l_10",
            "title": "Neil Armstrong",
            "length": 321
        },
        {
            "__typename": "Module",
            "id": "l_11",
            "title": "Yuri Gagarin",
            "length": 470
        },
        {
            "__typename": "Module",
            "id": "l_12",
            "title": "Buzz Aldrin",
            "length": 545
        },
        {
            "__typename": "Module",
            "id": "l_13",
            "title": "John Glenn",
            "length": 357
        },
        {
            "__typename": "Module",
            "id": "l_14",
            "title": "Chris Hadfield",
            "length": 223
        }
    ],
    "description": "Be inspired by famous catstronauts who have made their names legend from across the galaxies. Special guest appearance included, so hold on to your boots!"
}
```

Now the **readFragment** example (all fields):

```
const track = client.readFragment({
    id: 'Track:c_1',
    fragment: gql`
      fragment MyTrack on Track {
        id
        title
        author {
          id
          name
          photo
        }
        thumbnail
        length
        modulesCount
        numberOfViews
        modules {
          id
          title
          length
        }
        description
      }
    `
  });
```

The result is the same as in the case of the **readyQuery**.

---

Now the example with the ***partial*** fields.
For the **readQuery**:

```
  const { track } = client.readQuery({
    query: gql`
      query getTrack($trackId: ID!) {
        track(id: $trackId) {
          id
          title
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: { // Provide any required variables here.  Variables of mismatched types will return `null`.
      trackId: 'c_1',
    },
  });
```

The result will be:

```
{
    "__typename": "Track",
    "id": "c_1",
    "title": "FAMOUS CATSTRONAUTS"
}
```

The **readFragment** (partial fields)

```
  const track = client.readFragment({
    id: 'Track:c_1',
    fragment: gql`
      fragment MyTrack on Track {
        id
        title
      }
    `
  });
```

The result will be the same as **readyQuery**!

My question: When should I use the **readQuery** and when the **readFragment**? It looks like they provide the same result.

---

The same for **writeQuery** and the **writeFragment**. They do the same at the first look.

**writeQuery** partial update code example:

```
client.writeQuery({
    query: gql`
      query WriteTrack($trackId: ID!) {
        track(id: $trackId) {
          id
          title

        },
      }`,
      data: { // Contains the data to write
      track: {
        __typename: 'Track',
        id: 'c_1',
        title: 'Buy grapes ',
      },
      
    },
    variables: {
      id: 'c_1'
    }
  })
```

**writeFragment** partial update code example:

```
 client.writeFragment({
    id: 'Track:c_1',
    fragment: gql`
    fragment MyTrack on Track {
      id
      title
    }
  `,
  data: {
    __typename: 'Track',
    id: 'c_1',
    title: 'Buy grapes ',
  }
  })
```

The result is the same. Both update the title. So what is the difference? 
 When should I use the **writeQuery** and when the **writeFragment**?
Thanks for any help and your patience and time!